# Python NameError: name is not defined (related to having default input argument types)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, nameerror

I have a problem with the fact that I am calling `len(myByteArray)` in the input arguments to a function I am declaring. I'd like that to be a default argument, but Python doesn't seem to like it. `myByteArray` is of type `bytearray`. See [documentation on bytearray here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray). I am accessing its built-in `find` function, [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) (see "bytes.find").

My function:

```
def circularFind(myByteArray, searchVal, start=0, end=len(myByteArray)):
    """
    Return the first-encountered index in bytearray where searchVal 
    is found, searching to the right, in incrementing-index order, and
    wrapping over the top and back to the beginning if index end < 
    index start
    """
    if (end >= start):
        return myByteArray.find(searchVal, start, end)
    else: #end < start, so search to highest index in bytearray, and then wrap around and search to "end" if nothing was found 
        index = myByteArray.find(searchVal, start, len(myByteArray))
        if (index == -1):
            #if searchVal not found yet, wrap around and keep searching 
            index = myByteArray.find(searchVal, 0, end)
        return index
```

Examples to attempt to use the function above:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
#EXAMPLES:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
#Only executute this block of code if running this module directly,
#*not* if importing it
#-see here: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm
if __name__ == "__main__": #if running this module as a stand-alone program
    import random
    random.seed(0)

    bytes = bytearray(100)
    for i in range(len(bytes)):
        bytes[i] = int(random.random()*256)

    print(list(bytes)); print();

    print('built-in method:')
    print(bytes.find(255))
    print(bytes.find(2,10,97))
    print(bytes.find(5,97,4))

    print('\ncircularFind:')
    print(circularFind(bytes,255))
    print(circularFind(bytes,2,10,97))
    print(circularFind(bytes,5,97,4))
```

Error:

> NameError: name 'myByteArray' is not defined

If I just remove my default arguments (`=0` and `=len(myByteArray)`), however, it works fine. But...I really want those default arguments there so that the `start` and `end` arguments are optional. What do I do?

In C++ this would be easy, as argument types are specified when you write functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python default arguments are evaluated when the function is defined. Rather, you want something like this:

```
def circularFind(myByteArray, searchVal, start=0, end=None):
    """
    Return the first-encountered index in bytearray where searchVal 
    is found, searching to the right, in incrementing-index order, and
    wrapping over the top and back to the beginning if index end < 
    index start
    """
    if end is None:
        end = len(myByteArray)
    # continue doing what you were doing
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of passing the parameters, the parameters are not initialised

```
>>> def a(b=1,c=b):
...     print(c,b)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

so you need to send len of myByteArray as another variable.

So what you could do is,

```
def circularFind(myByteArray, searchVal, start=0, end=-1):
    if end == -1:
        end = len(myByteArray)
    #reset of code here.
```